# $.inArray always returning -1 for array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var myWidth = 20;
var myHeight = 30;

allDims = [
  {w: 20, h: 30},
  {w: 10, h: 15}
]

if ($.inArray({w: myWidth, h: myHeight}, allDims) !== -1) {
   ...
}
```

Why is the if-condition always returning -1?

Comment: It's always -1 because one object is never equal to another object, even if they contain the same data. The only exception to that rule is when the object stored in the array is stored by reference, and the object you're testing with is also a reference to that same object. In that case, they literally are the same object.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't work because the equality test on objects is based on the equality of references.

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) :

> Two distinct objects are never equal for either strictly or abstract
>   comparisons

So you must implement the index search yourself, by looping and comparing both `w` and `h`.

For example :

```
   var index = -1;
   for (var i=0; i<allDims.length; i++) {
      if (allDims[i].w==myWidth && allDims[i].h==myHeight) {
          index = i;
          break;
      }
   }
```

If you want something more elegant, you could use `filter` and pass a function, but it would iterate over the whole array even when not needed. A generic function similar to `indexOf` but taking a callback to check equality can be designed :

```
Array.prototype.indexFunc = function(o, equal) {
  for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
     if (equal(o,this[i])) return i;
  }
  return -1;
}
console.log(allDims.indexFunc({w:10, h:15}, function(a,b) {
       return a.w==b.w && a.h==b.h
})); // logs 1
```

Comment: this answer does not deserve downvotes, it is 100% correct.  The other (current) answer does not deserve upvotes - it is 100% incorrect.